# Java checkstyle: how to check if a certaing method is wrapped

Tags: java, checkstyle, maven-checkstyle-plugin

How would I write a check which checks if a certain method of a certain class is wrapped?

For example, this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass
    .add(object1)
    .add(object2)
    .add(object3);
```

should pass, but this:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.add(object1).add(object2).add(object3);
```

should fail. Note that I want only this method of this class to be checked by this check.